# Changing acceleration of animation path

Tags: after-effects, animation, motion

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before but the search showed up nill for me. It could be I'm wording this wrong to be honest but I appreciate and help.

Essentially I have a shape that I have moving from one side of the screen to the other but instead of the animation moving at a linear speed, I want it to have an acceleration aspect to it (so it moves slower at first then speeds to full by the end)

Normally I do this by positioning and adding keyframes manually to make that effect, but it gets a bit time intensive. I'm wondering is there any effect or thing I can do to automatically add that in or make my life easier then doing it key frame by key frame?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: "Normally I do this by positioning and adding keyframes manually to make that effect" …really? That sounds so incredibly tredious.

Answer (score 1):

Keyframe interpolation is essentially what you're looking for here. One really easy way to achieve this is by using modifying your "keyframe velocity".

This article explains it better than I could:
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/speed.html